# Contraction Mapping Principal in $C^1[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $C^1[a,b]$ denote the space of real-valued functions with a continuous derivative on the interval $[a,b]$, with one-sided derivatives at the endpoints.

Let $\|f\| = |f(a)|+ \sup \{ |f'(t)|: a \leq t \leq b \}$ be the norm on the space.

Use the contraction mapping principal to prove that there is a continuously differentiable function $f$ on $[0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$ satisfying $f(0)=1$ and $5f'(x)= \sin (xf(x))$.

First note that the space is complete in this norm.

Since we are using the contraction mapping principal, we need to find a contraction.

By the definition of the space, I'm thinking about to use the mean-value theorem to find the contraction. e.g.  there exists $c$ such that $f'(c) = \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$. So we have $|f(b)-f(a)|\leq f'(c)|b-a|$. But I don't see this going anywhere.

I also thought about finding a sequence like the proof of the contraction mapping principal, something like $x_0= f_0$ and $x_n = f^n$. But I had trouble finding such contraction function.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: The thing you seem to be missing is that you need to set it up so that a fixed point of your map is a solution to the equation that you are trying to solve. i.e. The equation will be your guide to how to define the contraction map.

Comment: Maybe you can solve this problem if you check the machinery or the proof behind the existence and uniquness of ODE's using Banach fixed point theorem i.e. contraction mapping principal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$F(f)(x) = 1 + \frac15\int_{0}^{x}\sin (tf(t))\, \mathrm dt$$

\begin{align}
\left\|F(f) - F(g)\right\| &= |F(f)(0) - F(g)(0)| + \sup\limits_{t\in \left[0,\frac\pi2\right]} \left|F(f)'(t) - F(g)'(t)\right|\\
&=\frac15\sup\limits_{t\in \left[0,\frac\pi2\right]} \left|\sin (tf(t)) - \sin (tg(t))\right|\\
&\le \frac15\times\frac\pi{2} \sup\limits_{t\in \left[0,\frac\pi2\right]}\left|f(t)-g(t)\right|\\
&\le \frac\pi{10}\left(\left|f(0) - g(0)\right| + \sup\limits_{t\in \left[0,\frac\pi2\right]}\left|\int_{0}^t \left(f'(s)-g'(s)\right)\mathrm d s\right|\right)\\
&\le \frac\pi{10}\left(\left|f(0) - g(0)\right| + \frac\pi 2\sup\limits_{t\in \left[0,\frac\pi2\right]}\left|f'(t)-g'(t)\right|\right)\\
&\le \frac{\pi}{10}\times \frac{\pi}2 \left\|f-g\right\|\\
&= \frac{\pi^2}{20}\left\|f-g\right\|
\end{align}

Since $\frac{\pi^2}{20} < 1$, here you have your contraction. You can have a function $f$ such that, $$F(f) = f$$

Comment: How did you get $\sup |tf'(t)-tg'(t)|$ in the 4th line? Where did the $t$ in side the absolute value come from? Thank you for your help!

Comment: I made an edit to the answer. I hope it is clear now.